# How to get the same accuracy value as model.fit

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

In the following keras model, I added "`my_accuracy`" and "`accuracy`" into the `model.compile`, and then run `model.fit`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

xx = np.random.rand(28,28,1).astype(np.float32)

yy = np.random.rand(28,28,1).astype(np.float32)

zz = np.random.rand(28,28,1).astype(np.float32)

x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(x, y)
model.summary()

def my_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.keras.metrics.binary_accuracy(tf.round(y_true), tf.round(y_pred))

model.compile(
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
    metrics = [
        my_accuracy,
        "accuracy",
    ]
)

history = model.fit(xx, yy, epochs = 2, verbose = 1)
```

**Here is the output:**

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(None, 28, 28, 1)]       0         
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 28, 28, 1)         2         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 2
Trainable params: 2
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/2
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28, 28, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 28, 1, 1).

WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28, 28, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 28, 1, 1).

WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28, 28, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 28, 1, 1).

WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28, 28, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 28, 1, 1).

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 354ms/step - loss: 0.1529 - my_accuracy: 0.4566 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1527 - my_accuracy: 0.4554 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

And then, call the `my_accuracy` directly:

```
my_pred = model.predict(yy, verbose=0)
my_acc = my_accuracy(yy, my_pred).numpy()

print("my_acc: {}", my_acc)
```

And the result:

```
my_acc: {} [[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 0. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 0. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 1. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 0. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 0. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 1. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 0. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 0. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 1. 0.]]

 ...

 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 0. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 0. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 1. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 0. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 0. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 1. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 0. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 0. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 1. 0.]]]
```

**For "my_accuracy":**

When calling `my_accuracy` directly, the result is an `array`, but the value of `model.fit` is just a number `0.4566`.

How to get the same result as `model.fit` (`0.4566`) when calling the method directly?

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 354ms/step - loss: 0.1529 - my_accuracy: 0.4566 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

**For "accuracy":**

What is the real method of `accuracy`? Why is the value equal to `0.0000e+00`?

**For the warning:**

Why this warning says `shape (None, 28, 1, 1)`? Where is the `shape (None, 28, 1, 1)`?

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28, 28, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 28, 1, 1).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot of your problems stem from a wrong `input_shape`. You have `28,28,1` sized data. But your model's input shape is `(None, 28, 28, 1)` i.e. TensorFlow automatically adds a batch dimension in the front. So let's change your model as follows.

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 1))
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(x, y)
```

This fixes the model.

> What is the real method of accuracy? Why is the value equal to 0.0000e+00?

You have `float` values in your labels (i.e. yy). Accuracy is computed with labels being 0 or 1. None of the predictions going to exactly match when they are floating values, thus you get an accuracy of 0. Replace `yy` with something like `np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(28,28,1))` and you'll get non-zero accuracy, matching the value computed by `my_accuracy`.

> Why this warning says shape (None, 28, 1, 1)? Where is the shape (None, 28, 1, 1)?

This is basically saying the model is not getting correct input shape. It's because of the incorrect input shape of the model.

Comment: Thank you so much. After changing the `shape=(28, 1)`, I still get `an array` result from the `my_accuracy`. When I try to print the shape with this code: `print("my_acc.shape: {}", my_acc.shape)`, the output is: `my_acc.shape: {} (28, 28)`. It is still not a `single number` as `model.fit`. I want to get the `single number of predict result` from test dataset one by one. What's missing in my code for the `my_acc = my_accuracy(yy, my_pred).numpy()`?

Comment: If you want the single number just use `np.mean(my_acc)`. You have a label set of `28x28x1` a prediction set of the same size. Which means your accuracy matrix will be `28x28` (1 item for each sample). You just take the mean of this to get a single value